# Why is Mas Amedda unquestionably loyal to Palpatine even when he knows his darkest secrets?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

This strikes me as odd, how did Palpatine obtain Mas Amedda's complete loyalty even after revealing some, if not all, of his secrets, did Mas Amedda hate the Jedi and/or the Republic? What exactly moved him to aid in Palpatine's plans to create a fake war that would end up in the death of all Jedi?

Comment: It’s a big galaxy. Why shouldn’t there be plenty of people who just don’t care about the death of a bunch of Jedi they’ve never met? Besides,  being one of Palpatine’s right-hand people has its perks.

Comment: Still, he should have a motive, credits and power could have easily been obtained if he ratted out Palpatine to the Jedi/Senate so he should have a bigger motive than just obtaining credits.

Comment: Generally speaking, being a whistleblower in a democratic government is not nearly as reliable a route to money and power as being in the inner circle of an absolute dictator. Besides, would *you* want to be the one to betray the Lord of the Sith? I know *I* wouldn’t!

Comment: Fair enough, but see it this way, you could come up that after a long investigation, you found out that Palpatine is Sidious and he was the one responsible for the whole war, the Jedi and the Senate would be glad that you ended the horror that is the Clone Wars and you would have a big head start for the next Chancellor Election, as for protection, you'd have the whole Jedi Order protecting you while Palpatine is being taken care of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's very little to go on, but I did find this passage about Mas Amedda's internal thought process from '[Aftermath: Life Debt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath%3A_Life_Debt)' to be very telling.

> *"It is lonely being the head of a dying Empire.
> He is a figurehead. Or worse than one. They don’t even trot him out for appearances. His office and his chambers make up his prison. It’s here he mostly stays. Taking in his meals. Watching the HoloNet. Thinking about his future, or rather, the lack of his future.
> It wasn’t supposed to be like this.
> Palpatine was supposed to remain. The Emperor was as certain a fixture in the galaxy as the Core itself. As fundamental as the Imperial Palace. Timeless and immortal."*

My read on it is that Mas is a follower, not a leader and Palpatine promised him a place of power and prestige in his Empire. This is especially evident elsewhere in the book where it's made clear he has no idea what to do without Palpatine.

It probably started small. A secret here, a favour there. At some point he saw Sidious's true face and for whatever reason, decided it was better (and probably healthier) to stand by him than against him.

Comment: Thanks! I could find very little to no information on him, much less his motives to stick out with Palpatine.